# Scaling and selecting unique records per worker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, scaling

I'm part of a project where we are having to deal with a lot of data in a stream. It's going to be passed to Mongo and from there it needs to be processed by workers to see if it needs to be persisted, amongst other things, or discarded.

We want to scale this horizontally. My question is, what methods are there for ensuring that each worker selects a unique record, that isn't already being processed by another worker?

Is a central main worker required to hand out jobs to the sub workers, if that is the case, the bottle neck and point of failure is with that central worker, right?

Any ideas or suggestions welcome.

Thanks!

Josh

Comment: Simple method, One need to maintain Flag Variable, that the file is opened/processed.. read it and do take action accordingly!

Comment: I've used that before, but I just fear that if so many workers are fighting for things to do, what is stopping two or more workers grabbing the same record/job at the same time?

Comment: now a day DB are getting smarter, please dont use any dirty read and you should be good.. some events are just not in our hand.. that are 0.001% probability so let it occur. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`findAndModify`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/) to both select and flag a document atomically, making sure that only one worker gets to process it. My experience is that this can be slow due to excessive database locking, but that experience is based on MongoDB 2.x so it may not be an issue anymore on 3.x.

Also, with MongoDB it's difficult to "wait" for new jobs/documents (you can tail the oplog, but you'd have to do this from every worker and each one will wake up and perform the `findAndModify()` query, resulting in the aforementioned locking).

I think that ultimately you should consider using a proper messaging solution (write data to MongoDB, write the `_id` to the broker, have the workers subscribe to the message queue, and if you configure things properly only one worker will get a job). Well-known brokers are [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/), [nsq.io](http://nsq.io/) and with a bit of extra work you can even use [Redis](http://redis.io/).

Comment: Thank you - after some more research we're settling with Bull which uses Redis.